# UITextfield interferes with swipe gestures

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've implemented this custom control in my project: [Github page](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell) this control adds a Mailbox like swipe to delete/complete feature which I would like to use.

The only problem I've encountered when using this is if I add a UITextField to the cell via storyboards. When I add one the cell stops recognizing the gestures and only lets me interact with the UITextField.

Does anyone have a remedy for this problem?

Edit: Here is the initializer method of the TableViewCell. Sorry.

```
- (void)initializer
{
    _mode = MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch;

    _colorIndicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [_colorIndicatorView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [_colorIndicatorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self insertSubview:_colorIndicatorView belowSubview:self.contentView];

    _slidingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [_slidingImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    [_colorIndicatorView addSubview:_slidingImageView];

    _panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGestureRecognizer:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];
    [_panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
}
```

and the method for handling the gesture

```
- (void)handlePanGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state          = [gesture state];
    CGPoint translation                     = [gesture translationInView:self];
    CGPoint velocity                        = [gesture velocityInView:self];
    CGFloat percentage                      = [self percentageWithOffset:CGRectGetMinX(self.contentView.frame) relativeToWidth:CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration        = [self animationDurationWithVelocity:velocity];
    _direction = [self directionWithPercentage:percentage];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
    }
    else if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint center = {self.contentView.center.x + translation.x, self.contentView.center.y};
        [self.contentView setCenter:center];
        [self animateWithOffset:CGRectGetMinX(self.contentView.frame)];
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
    }
    else if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
        _currentImageName = [self imageNameWithPercentage:percentage];
        _currentPercentage = percentage;
        MCSwipeTableViewCellState state = [self stateWithPercentage:percentage];

        if (_mode == MCSwipeTableViewCellModeExit && _direction != MCSwipeTableViewCellDirectionCenter && [self validateState:state])
            [self moveWithDuration:animationDuration andDirection:_direction];
        else
            [self bounceToOriginWithDirection:_direction];
    }
}
```

Comment: Either post the code you have trouble with or just go back to guy who made the control you are using and ask him for help. We are here to help if you have trouble with a code and by seeing it we can help you.

Comment: The codes you posted are perfectly fine. It should work. Where is the code for the text field? You are adding it through storyboard, but where is the code for it in order to connect it and fire the gesture event?

Comment: I had added this `[self.itemLabel addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];` (itemLabel is my textField) within my `initWithStyle` method but it didn't seem to work. Should I add this to a custom initializer?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you can try that. Any way I'm going to download that control and take a look at it. In the meanwhile someone else may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, and for going even further to help.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you, I was just wondering if you had found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to fix this problem. I added a UITextField subclass to my project, then imported the UITextfield header into the custom UITableViewCell. Adding the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to the `@interface`. Add `@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) ItemLabel *label; // ItemLabel being the UITextField class` to the `UITableViewCell` class, synthesize it in your implementation.

Then add this code in your custom initializer or the default one if you don't have a custom one:

```
_label = [[TehdaLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
_label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
_label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_label.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
_label.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
_label.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:_label];
```

Then add your delegate methods for UITextField and be merry.
Seems as if the UITextField was interfering because it was not a subview of the cell.